# MyISAM vs InnoDB for quick inserts and a composite unique key

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, composite-primary-key

Context: I'm creating a multi-threaded application that will be inserting/updating rows very frequently.

Originally I had the following table:

```
#TABLE 1
CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  `state` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `state`))
ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

However after doing some research I found that MySQL uses table-level locking for MyISAM tables permitting only one session to update those tables at a time ([source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-locking.html)). Not good for a multi-threaded application making frequent changes to the table.

As such, it was suggested that I switch from a composite primary key to an auto-generated primary key with a unique index for id/state. This would allow for quick inserts while still enforcing the unique combination of the id/state.

```
#TABLE 2
CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `key` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  `state` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`key`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_STATE` (`id` ASC, `state` ASC))
ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

InnoDB however avoids table locks and instead uses row-level locking ([source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-locking.html)) so I thought of switching over to the following:

```
#TABLE 3
CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `key` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  `state` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`key`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_STATE` (`id` ASC, `state` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

But after reading up about InnoDB, I discovered InnoDB organizes data using a clustered index and secondary indexes require multiple look ups. One for the secondary index and another for the primary key ([source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html)). As such I'm debating switching to the following:

```
#TABLE 4
CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  `state` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `state`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I'm wondering if all my assumptions are correct:

1. MyISAM table locks the entire table for INSERTS, UPDATES, and DELETES permitting only one session to update those tables at a time
2. InnoDB handles INSERTS with composite primary keys quicker than MyISAM. This is because InnoDB, unlike MyISAM, does not lock the entire table to scan and reserve a new primary key.
3. When using InnoDB I should make a composite primary key rather than a composite unique index because a secondary index requires multiple look ups.
4. I should be using Table 4

Comment: (2) is a *non sequitur*.

Comment: You're right, I've updated it to better clarify what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1-yes, 2-yes, 3-yes, 4-yes.

Also...

- Do you really need `BIGINT`?  Won't 4 billion values in `INT UNSIGNED` suffice?  (And save half the space.)  Presumably `id` is the PK of some other table?  If so, that table would need changing, too.
- Can `state` be normalized?  Or turned into an `ENUM`?  Again saving space.

Item 3 is worse than mentioned because of the need to lock on two unique keys.

Comment: Can you clarify what you meant by "worse than mentioned?" Are you saying that creating a composite secondary index requires more than just two look ups? P.S. Good points all of them. I never thought about `BIGINT(10)` being 10 billion and `INT UNSIGNED` being 4 billion.

Comment: `BIGINT` is a 64-bit number `+/- 8 billion billion`; the `(10)` says _nothing_.